# Creating dynamic shotcuts paths

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I created a windows application in .net framework 3.5 and it is working fine in the way of setup installation. In the setup I created shortcut for the main exe. The shortcut not created in the user program menu or desktop. The shortcut only created in side the same application path only.

(i.e.) let, my application setup is installing in the path "H:\UserProject\UserDlls\" and "H:\UserProject\UserShortCut\". Inside "H:\UserProject\UserDlls\" this folder all of my required dlls, exes and resources and inside "H:\UserProject\UserShortCut\" this folder only one short cut is available. That shortcut pointing "H:\UserProject\UserDlls\MainOutput.exe". This is installtion path scenario and I can't see the shortcut in user desktop or in start programs menu.

The problem is "H:\" drive is external hard disk drive and my machine has more than one usp drives. So in sime plugins it is showing some differnt drive names (not "H:\"). At that time the shotcut not working. Because in the shortcut I used fixed path (i.e.)"H:\" drive. So I want to give dynamic shotcut path.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In visual studio's setup project you should create shortcut and move it to **User's Desktop** and **User's Programs Menu**.

[image]